# powershell get-content path null error

Tags: powershell, path, null, runtime-error

```
$commonElementsLocation = ((Get-Location).Path + "\FolderMatchingCommonWords.txt")

if ($commonElementsLocation) {
    $result += Start-Job -InitializationScript { 
                   $commonElements = Get-Content -Path $commonElementsLocation
               } -ScriptBlock $testScriptBlock -ArgumentList "testing" | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here - probably a stupid mistake, but I put a condition around the Start-Job statement, and powershell still gives the following error:

```
Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:1 char:39
+  $commonElements = (Get-Content -Path $commonElementsLocation)
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentC
   ommand

Running startup script threw an error: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null..
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
```

Answer (score 1):

In v3 add $using:

```
....(Get-Content -Path $using:commonElementsLocation...
```

Comment: Correct.  The job runs in a completely separate PowerShell process. Whatever "outer" variables the init script is using should be referenced with `$using:<varname>` so they get serialized across to the PowerShell session running the job.

Answer (score 0):

You have already used a variable for a script block once with `$testScriptBlock`. You could just do that again for `-InitializationScript`?

```
$anotherSB = [scriptblock]::create("$commonElements = (Get-Content -Path $commonElementsLocation)")
$result += Start-Job -InitializationScript $anotherSB -ScriptBlock $testScriptBlock -ArgumentList "testing" | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```